# Frameworks used by a third-party library

Tags: ios, xcode, terminal

Is there a way to print all of frameworks used by a third-party library?

My app rejected by using a non-public api. 
I want to check if it is caused by my third-party libraries.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `otool`(1) with `-L` for that, e.g.:

```
otool -L libThirdParty.a
```

for libraries or

```
otool -L ThirdParty.framework/ThirdParty
```

for frameworks.